# Debug assertion failed (Buffer too small) constructor initialization

Tags: c++, oop

I wrote a code...I had to use "strcpy_s" in it...the program is compiling but I'm getting debug assertion failed...I researched a bit and found that this error occurs due to incorrect size in the "strcpy_s" parameters...but I double checked and my size is ok...I can't understand why it's not  working...Any help will be welcomed....Anticipated thanks...One more thing I need to initialize the constructor members in the constructor itself (it's instructed in my project...)

From the header file

```
class CyclicShift
{
private:
char fUpperCase[26];//A-Z
char fLowerCase[26];//a-z

public:
CyclicShift();
```

In the .cpp file (initializing the constructor)

```
CyclicShift::CyclicShift()
{
strcpy_s(fUpperCase, sizeof (fUpperCase), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
strcpy_s(fLowerCase, sizeof (fLowerCase), "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::string`?

Answer (score 4):

You `char` buffers must be 27 `char`s long. For the 26 letters of the alphabet, plus a trailing '\0' chararacter, that all C-style strings have.